# Ordenar Arraylist de objetos Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo dos Arraylist que los uno, y el problema al unirlos es que me queda el primer array list ordenado partiendo en 1 hasta el 9 por ejemplo, y el segundo arraylist desde el 5 al 9 pero posterior al 9 del primer arraylist, existe alguna manera de poder ordenarlos ya una vez "unidos". El Collections.sort no me funciona la verdad ( no se por qué ) si me pueden ayudar....

```
ArrayList<CuentaMatriz> listar_CuentasMatriz    =   new CuentaMatrizData().listar_ctas_matrices_new....
ArrayList<CuentaMatriz> listar_CuentasMatrizMunicipal   =   new ArrayList<CuentaMatriz>();
listar_CuentasMatrizMunicipal   =   new CuentaMatrizData().listar_ctas_matricesDetalles....

ArrayList<CuentaMatriz> Coincidencia = new ArrayList<CuentaMatriz>();

            for(int i = 0; i<listar_CuentasMatriz.size();i++) {
                for(int k = 0; k<listar_CuentasMatrizMunicipal.size();k++) {
                    if(listar_CuentasMatrizMunicipal.get(k).getCodigoCuenta().equals(listar_CuentasMatriz.get(i).getCodigoCuenta())) {
                        listar_CuentasMatrizMunicipal.remove(k);
                          duplicates++;
                        Coincidencia.add(listar_CuentasMatriz.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        LISTComparator playerComparator = new LISTComparator();
        Collections.sort(Coincidencia, playerComparator);



public class LISTComparator implements Comparator<CuentaMatriz> { 
    public int compare(CuentaMatriz ListarCuenta, CuentaMatriz ListarCuentaM) { 
        return ListarCuenta.getCodigoCuenta().compareTo(ListarCuentaM.getCodigoCuenta()); 
        } 
    };
```

Donde Coincidencia es el nuevo arraylist que contiene ambos

las cuentas (ambas) traen codigos por ejemplo *primer arraylist 412-05-01, 412-05-02 , 412-05-03 ,412-08-01 ,412-08-02 y la otra cuenta (una vez que haya sacado los replicados, trae 412-06-01, 412-06-02, 412-07-01, 412-07-02...

Por lo que en Coincidencia los trae así 412-05-01, 412-05-02 , 412-05-03 ,412-08-01 ,412-08-02, 412-06-01, 412-06-02, 412-07-01, 412-07-02 y no ordenados...

necsito ayuda en que pueda ordenarlos quedando así 412-05-01, 412-05-02 , 412-05-03 , 412-06-01, 412-06-02, 412-07-01, 412-07-02, 412-08-01 ,412-08-02

Comment: Tienes que evitar duplicados? Eso es trivial usando un Set. Y en tu código de ejemplo no se ve dónde intentas usar sort. Procura incluir en tu pregunta un ejemplo completo de lo que intentas hacer, junto con datos de prueba y el resultado que esperas :)

Comment: @Alfabravo SÍ, tengo que evitar el duplicado, y no está puesto el sort, porque me da error, pero lo pondria debajo del Coincidencia.add....

Comment: Si lo pones justo debajo, vas a hacer sort M*N veces, donde M y N son las longitudes de los arraylists. Tampoco añade mucho valor que elimines elementos de uno de los arrays de origen si estás construyendo el resultado en el arraylist Coincidencia. Por favor, intenta incluir el sort, actualiza tu código y nos cuentas cuál es el resultado (_no funciona_ no nos dice mucho).

Comment: @Alfabravo este error me arroja el .sort "The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<CuentaMatriz>)" al querer usarlo como Collections.sort(Coincidencia); fuera de dicho For

Comment: Eso es seguramente (sin yo ver el código de esa clase) porque no es evidente para el compilador cómo ordenar instancias de CuentaMatriz. Cómo debería ordenarlas?

Comment: las cuentas (ambas) traen codigos por ejemplo *primer arraylist 412-05-01, 412-05-02 , 412-05-03 ,412-08-01 ,412-08-02  y la otra cuenta (una vez que haya sacado los replicados, trae 412-06-01, 412-06-02,  412-07-01,  412-07-02...Por lo que en Coincidencia los trae así  412-05-01, 412-05-02 , 412-05-03 ,412-08-01 ,412-08-02, 412-06-01, 412-06-02,  412-07-01,  412-07-02 y no ordenados... ( y eso es lo que necsito que pueda ordenarlos quedando así  412-05-01, 412-05-02 , 412-05-03 , 412-06-01, 412-06-02,  412-07-01,  412-07-02, 412-08-01 ,412-08-02 @Alfabravo

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta, incluye los datos del comentario y la definición de la clase CuentaMatriz.

Comment: El error de compilación que tienes al usar el `Collections.sort()` se debe a que la clase `CuentaMatriz` no implementa la interfaz `Comparable`. Para poder comparar objetos en Java, y por ende también para usar estos métodos de ordenación, estos deben implentar dicha interfaz.

Comment: @E.Betanzos mmmmmm me podrias guiar un poco más con ese tema de la interfaz Comparable ? o como tendría que hacerlo ?

Comment: Mira, el método `Collections.sort()` tiene dos variantes. [La primera](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) espera una lista de objetos comparables y [la segunda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) una lista de objetos, que no tienen que ser comparables, y un `Comparator`. Mira [aquí](https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparator-comparable) como usar ambas variantes.

Comment: @E.Betanzos he intentado lo sgte, 
 public class PlayerRankingComparator implements Comparator<CuentaMatriz> {
    
      
     public int compare(CuentaMatriz firstPlayer, CuentaMatriz secondPlayer) {
        return (firstPlayer.getCodigoCuenta() - secondPlayer.getCodigoCuenta());
     }
 }

Pero el "getCodigoCuenta()" es un string y este es el error The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String

Comment: `return firstPlayer.getCodigoCuenta().compareTo(secondPlayer.getCodigoCuenta())`

Comment: @E.Betanzos agregue el collection, pero me sigue arrojando "desordeando" el arraylist "Coincidir" (agregue modificacion al codigo)

Comment: [Sigamos en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110173/ordenar-arraylist-de-objetos-java)